# Hostapd giving psk mismatch for fitbit aria scale

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, wireless-access-point, bridge, hostapd

I have been trying to get my fitbit aria connected to an orange pi (think raspberry pi).

I have got clients connected using this config, however the fitbit aria gives me a `AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH` error from hostapd.

Here is the output from `hostapd`

```
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd
wlan0: STA 20:f8:5e:b3:0e:fd IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
```

Here is the `hostapd.conf` config file

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=orangepi
hw_mode=b
channel=6
wpa=2
auth_algs=1
wpa_passphrase=passwordpasswordpassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
#wpa_psk_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.wpa_psk
bridge=br0
wmm_enabled=0
logger_stdout=1
logger_stdout_level=2
```

Script I'm using to make the ap and bridge the connection with eth0

```
#/bin/sh
killall wpa_supplicant
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan0

dhclient br0

hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If I turn off authentication it does connect...

Comment: Does the same happen if you downgrade hostapd configuration to WPA1-TKIP?

Comment: I was just about to try but the batteries on the scale just died aha. Will report back tmr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being dhcp problems. I hadn't set up dnsmasq to relay dhcp through to the gateway.

I added the two lines to the script:

`killall dnsmasq`

`dnsmasq --dhcp-relay=<local address>,<server address>`

And replaced the ip addresses within the <>, and voila.

It works, I won't say it is particularly stable aha.

```
#/bin/sh
killall wpa_supplicant
killall dnsmasq
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan0

dhclient br0
dnsmasq --dhcp-relay=<local address>,<server address>
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```